# BFD: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 3699

Tags: mingw, gprof

I have installed MinGWDistro 15.0 in my computer.

And when I run this in cmd

```
g++ "snackstore.cpp" -o "snackstore.exe" -g -pg
snackstore.exe
gprof.exe "snackstore.exe" gmon.out > gmon.txt
```

I get this error

```
BFD: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 3699.
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I had the same error when compiling "g++ -o main.o main.cpp" instead of "g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp" before "g++ -o main.exe main.o"